# Unbuffered bidirectional data streaming with gRPC: how to get the size of the client-side buffer?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am streaming data from a server to a client and I would like the server not to read and send more data than the client's buffer size.

Given:

```
service StreamService {
  rpc Stream(stream Buffer) returns (stream Buffer);
}

message Buffer {
  bytes data = 1;
}
```

My client's program basically looks like:

```
func ReadFromServer(stream StreamService_StreamClient, buf []byte) (n int, err error) {
  // I actually don't need more than len(buf)...
  // How could I send len(buf) while stream is bidirectional...?
  buffer, err := stream.Recv()
  if err != nil {
     return 0,  err
  }
  n = copy(buf, buffer.Data)
  // buf could also be smaller than buffer.Data...
  return n, nil
}
```

So how could I send `len(buf)` while the RPC's stream is bidirectional, i.e. the send direction is used by another independent stream of data? Note that I don't use client or server-side buffering to avoid loosing data when one of them is terminated (my data-source is an I/O).

Comment: The server can't get any information about the client that the client doesn't expose. The client would need to tell the server what its buffer size is if it wants the server to know.

Comment: That's my question, how would you send it in this case? `stream.Send()` is used already busy sending client's data.

Answer (score 3):

gRPC provides no mechanism for this. It only provides push-back when a sender needs to slow down. But there will still be buffering happening internally and that is not exposed because gRPC is message-based, not byte-based.

There's really only two options in your case:

1. Server chunks responses arbitrarily. The client `Recv()`s when necessary and any extra is manually managed for later.
2. The client sends a request asking for a precise amount to be returned, and then waits for the response.

> Note that I don't use client or server-side buffering to avoid loosing data when one of them is terminated (my data-source is an I/O).

This isn't how it works. When you do a `Send()` there is no guarantee it is received when the call returns. When you do a `Recv()` there is no guarantee that the message was received after the recv call (it could have been received before the call). There is buffering going on, period.

Comment: Ok but at least it would buffer what the client actually wanted (the message's size would be equal to the client's requested size). I'm thinking of trying to split this single RPC into two distincts unidirectional RPCs `Read(Size) returns (Buffer)` and using some metadata to tell the server they are actually correlated and should use the same I/O file descriptor. What do you think of this approach?

Comment: I'd probably just make an additional request type in the bidi stream (via a oneof) to issue the read request in-line. But what you suggested could work fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no built-in solution for that. The use-case looks little bit weird: why server must care about client's state at all? If it really needs to, you should extend your bidirectional stream: the client must request byte slices of a particular size (according to the own buffer size and other factors).

By the way, you may find useful message size limit settings GRPC client and server:
https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#MaxMsgSize https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#WithMaxMsgSize